# Does a moving star have a larger gravitational pull?

Tags: general-relativity

A moving star's relativistic mass is larger than its rest mass. Is its gravitational pull larger?

What about its inertial mass? Does it have larger inertial mass, keeping in mind that inertial mass should equal gravitational mass according to the equivalence principle.

I suppose this quote from wikipedia is relavant:

> However, it turns out that it is impossible to find an objective
>   general definition for the concept of invariant mass in general
>   relativity. At the core of the problem is the non-linearity of the
>   Einstein field equations, which makes it impossible to write the
>   gravitational field energy as part of the Stress–energy tensor in a
>   way that is invariant for all observers. For a given observer, this
>   can be achieved by the Stress–energy–momentum pseudotensor.[21]

Comment: Yes, I did not see that one. But it doesn't answer the inertial mass aspect. I recall reading that inertial mass (resistance to a change in acceleration) does change with velocity and am trying to reconcile that with the fact that effective gravitational mass does not change just because the star is moving.